# hamburger activate css transition on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

The aim of my game - to get a hamburger icon to show transition to a cross on click, then when clicked again to revert back to its burger state.

I'm not CSS guru but have managed, through extensive googling) to get it to do the transition on hover and when clicked (but instantly reverts).

I am struggling to reach my goal, could someone please provide me with some pointers?

**Update**

As requested, here's a fiddle - [here](https://jsfiddle.net/20nqa5jr/)
Below is a section of the CSS that deals with the transition, I have tried using toggle from JQuery in order to trick the CSS into think that the mouse is still clicked down but couldn't get it to work, if this is possible (assume it is) is it an ill-advised method of achieving my aim?

**CSS**

```
.burge:active span {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.0);
    transition-delay: .2s;
}
.burger:active span:before {
    background-color:#7dcc3d;
    transition-property: margin, transform;
    transition-duration: .3s;
    transition-delay: .3s, 0;
}
.burger:active span:before {
    margin-top: 0;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    transition-delay: 0, .3s;
}
.burger:active span:after {
    background-color:#7dcc3d;
    transition-property: margin, transform;
    transition-duration: .3s;
    transition-delay: .3s, 0;
}
.burger:active span:after {
    margin-top: 0;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transition-delay: 0, .3s;
}
```

Comment: Use this SASS implementation tha already works great: https://github.com/jorenvanhee/sass-burger - Also, you should trigger this with Javascript as there is no guarantee that a click happened using only CSS. `:active` and `:hover` lose their states when something else is selected or when the mouse moves away respectively.

Comment: Thanks, that is cool, but would like to get this working as I've spent time working with all of this and feel I'm really close. - Just seen your edit, that's exactly the problem, had a bit of JS that wasn't doing the trick, will update the Q with what I had (when I remember/re-write) what I had.

Comment: can you set up a jsfiddle with your current progress working?

Comment: Done :) fiddle in the update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot detect a click with CSS, so thats rather an important detail. Basically, replace all your `:active` with a class (say `.active`) and trigger a toggleClass (jQuery) in javascript:

```
.burger.active span {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.0);
    transition-delay: .2s;
}
.burger.active span:before {
    background-color:#7dcc3d;
    transition-property: margin, transform;
    transition-duration: .3s;
    transition-delay: .3s, 0;
}
.burger.active span:before {
    margin-top: 0;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    transition-delay: 0, .3s;
}
.burger.active span:after {
    background-color:#7dcc3d;
    transition-property: margin, transform;
    transition-duration: .3s;
    transition-delay: .3s, 0;
}
.burger.active span:after {
    margin-top: 0;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transition-delay: 0, .3s;
}
```

Here the jQuery:

```
$(".burger").click(function(event){ $(this).toggleClass("active"); });
```

Or heres some pure JS:

```
var burgers = document.querySelectAll(".burger");
for(var i = 0; i < burgers.length; i++){
    burgers.item(i).addEventListener("click", function(){
        if(burger.className.indexOf("active").length){
            burger.className = burger.className.replace("active", "");
        } else {
            burger.className += " active";
        }
    }, false)
}
```

I know my quick and dirty implementation of `toggleClass` does not work in many edge cases, so preferably use the jQuery version (the pure JS version would confuse a class called 'js-active' and just leave the class 'js-', breaking code).

Comment: Your jQuery is pretty much what I was using earlier - something so simple as creating a class (didn't know you could do that, thought it had to be :active) - thanks a lot!!!

Comment: yes you can detect a click with css, :focus does a good job, though the interaction is not as potentially powerful and arguably it breaks the rule of separation of concern (i.e. you should use the javascript functional layer, rather than the css presentational layer to trigger an action based on a user generated event)

Comment: `:focus` is _not a click_ - it just means what it says, the element is the current focus. Since there a menu, clicking on anything else will remove the focus. In the context of a hamburger menu, using `:focus` seems like a bad idea.

Comment: @somethinghere - it's not a click event, but it's a response to click, the clicked element gets focus (as long as tabindex is defined) and it means you can acheive click effects in css, however, I don't really recommend it

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do this without using JS then you can use a checkbox.

Here is a very basic example of how you can create an open/close state button

```css
.burger + label {
  position: relative;
  
}
.burger + label:after {
  content: '☰'
}
.burger:checked + label:after {
  content: 'X'
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" class="burger"><label for="checkbox1"></label>
```

Comment: I like this idea. Got to remember this one, have not seen this before and it's quite clever to use a checkbox. +1!

Comment: what happens if you re-organise your HTML and your CSS breaks?

Comment: Yea I like the idea of being able to achieve this without using JS. Using those CSS modifiers you an mimic a lot of controls like accordions, pop up messages, light boxes..

Comment: @ToniLeigh the same problem exists if you change your `active` class to a different element, or not apply it to your body or something. Yes, its based on structure, but Javascript does that too.

Comment: Obviously it needs to be structured correctly for it to work.. You could also have an issue if using JS and you restructured the HTML